# From where do portals who sell bitcoins buy bitcoins?

Tags: exchanges

The internet is now full of portals who are selling bitcoins to single users.

Where do these companies buy bitcoins and at what prices?

Is there any central regulator who can decide critical issue on bitcons?

Comment: related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/who-controls-the-bitcoin-software

Comment: also related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/5406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From where these companies buy bitcoins and at what prices?

From people selling them at market rate of an exchange likely. People selling them at the END all got them from miners - that is how bitcoins come into existence.

> is there any central regulator who can decide critical issue on bitcons?

No. That is by design.

Answer (score 1):

They most likely acquire coins via the large exchanges like MtGox and BitStamp.

Bitcoin has no centralized regulator. Since it is an open source project, it evolves by consensus and critical issues are decided between the developers and miners.