# Who were the Bitcoin maintainers before 2014? When did maintainers gain/lose merge access?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, history, governance

The Bitcoin lead maintainer and co-maintainers have merge access (i.e. they can approve changes to Bitcoin source code). We can see who the maintainers were since 2014:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/verify-commits/trusted-keys

1. Is this a complete/accurate list of maintainers since 2014?
2. Is there a list of when maintainers had merge access before 2014?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/176/48884. Also a reddit post with tons more info on committers: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5riy1j/list_of_people_who_have_had_commit_access_to/

Comment: Incredible work Andrew. Cheers :-)

Comment: @AndrewChow you should copy your reddit post as an answer here for archiving sake, it seems to be exactly what OP is looking for.

Comment: I've updated the post in the other question and will mark this as a duplicate.