# Original default bitcoin script

Tags: script

Where can I read the original Bitcoin script for verifying the transactions?
Also, who controls the GitHub profile of bitcoin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I read the original Bitcoin script for verifying the transactions?

You should be able to find the source code on GitHub

e.g. https://github.com/trottier/original-bitcoin but I'd verify that before relying on it for anything important.

> who controls the GitHub profile of bitcoin?

Some subset of
https://bitcoin.org/en/development#bitcoin-core-contributors

See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/verify-commits/trusted-keys

---

See also:

- [Is there a list of core Bitcoin committers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/176/13866) (hat tip to [Pieter Wuille](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/208/pieter-wuille) for pointing this out)

Comment: For the list of maintainers, see this question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/176/208

Comment: @Pieter Thanks for pointing that out, link appended to answer.