# Who approves the merger of github pull requests to the Bitcoin Core master branch?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

Does it have to be one of the 5 Lead Maintainers, or who can merge a pull request to the Bitcoin Core master branch?

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#decision-making-process:

> Whether a pull request is merged into Bitcoin Core rests with the project merge maintainers.
>
> Maintainers will take into consideration if a patch is in line with the general principles of the project; meets the minimum standards for inclusion; and will judge the general consensus of contributors.

Any maintainer can approve merges. See [Is there a list of core Bitcoin committers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-there-a-list-of-core-bitcoin-committers) for a list of maintainers.

Comment: Have the Lead Maintainers divided up the code base into sections of responsibility?

Comment: Most maintainers have their own focus area. There is no lead maintainer.

Comment: What are those focus areas?

Comment: Read the linked answer. It's not entirely up-to-date (as pointed out in the comment there), but repeating things here will just result in more places that go out of date over time.