Why is there a separate bitcoin and bitcoin-core GitHub repo?
Can someone explain why these two repositories exist at the same time?
https://github.com/bitcoin
https://github.com/bitcoin-core
It is a bit confusing for a newcomer to the codebase what to actually trust.
Furthermore, is there some good intro somewhere that explains how access to this repository is managed? Like who can become eligible to approve merge requests and for what reasons could this right be stripped from a person again.
Thanks a lot!

For the merge access part/maintainers see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/119316/who-approves-the-merger-of-github-pull-requests-to-the-bitcoin-core-master-branc

Thank you very much! That answers my questions!
